# Crouch probelm (Unity2D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I press "c" just once, the character crouches just as I want it to. But when I hold "c" to crouch, the character goes under the collider of the ground.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU3Qc.png)

```
    //Crouch + Animation
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = crouching;
        player_collider.size = crouching_size;
        anim.SetBool("crouch_ing", true);
    }
    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = standing;
        player_collider.size = standing_size;
        anim.SetBool("crouch_ing", false);
    }
    //--------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to reproduce the issue, but I couldn't quite achieve it. I skipped the animation part, but I got exact same results when tapping the button and when holding it down.

I managed though, to make player appear inside the platform, by changing collider's offset. Collider sizes' were correct in both poses, but when you don't adjust the offset to the new size, it might make your collider being not where you want it to.

Nevertheless, the reason for your player appearing below ground collider is your player's collider bounds not matching the graphics. I got two ideas to fix it:

1. The collider's size and offset for both poses are incorrect. Check them during gameplay by selecting player game object -> navigate to BoxCollider2D -> click on edit collider button. This way, you will able to tell, if everything you set is correct and fix it accordingly.
2. Your collider's size and offset for both poses are correct, but your animation is moving your character in a way, that makes graphics to move out of collider's bounds hence creating leading to your problem. Make sure that you animate your character properly.